# Non uniqueness of a solution of a first order PDE: Exercise 9.23 (b) John Lee "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, characteristics

This question is part of exercise 9.23 of "Introduction to smooth manifold" of John Lee second edition. Prove the following equation has a global solution which is not unique
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u + y \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}u=0 \\
 u(x,1)=e^{-x}  $$
I have used the method of characteristics as specified by the hint, but I did not find any reason of why this Cauchy problem could have a non unique solution.
Here's what I have done
$$ \begin{cases}
    x'(t,s)=1 \\
    y'(t,s)=y(t,s) \\
    x(t,s)=s \\
    y(t,s)=1
    \end{cases}, $$
then I imposed the boundary condition and this brought me to $u(x,y)=y\cdot e^{-x}.$ But then how could I proceed to build another solution? Any suggestions? Could it be a misprint? In another post the author has pointed out a mistake in one of the questions of problem 9.23, could this be another error, or am I missing something? I have already checked the correction list of the book and there was no error mentioned about this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is $y=y_0 \, e^{x-x_0}$, so the characteristics passing through the points $(x_0,1)$ (where $u$ is given) fill out the upper half plane $y > 0$. Thus, they don't tell you anything about what $u$ is supposed to be in the lower half plane $y \le 0$, except that for a global solution you probably want $u$ to be nice (say class $C^1$) everywhere, and in particular across the line $y=0$. The general solution is $u(x,y)=f(y \, e^{-x})$ where $f(t)$ is some $C^1$-function, and to satisfy the given condition you have to take $f(t)=t$ for $t>0$, but you can continue this in any $C^1$ way that you like to $t \le 0$. For example, you may take $f(t)=t$ in that region too, but also for example $f(t)=t+t^2$.

Comment: By the way, your “other possible solution” satisfies the PDE but not the other condition, since $u(x,1) = x-1+e^{-x} \neq e^{-x}$.

Comment: thanks I edited it because it was indecent.

Comment: I can see how $f(ye^{-x})$ is a solution for any smooth $f$, but how do we know that the general solution has this form?

Comment: @TobErnack: If we are seeking $C^1$-solutions defined on all of $\mathbf{R}^2$, we can use the chain rule and a change of variables $(\xi,\eta)=(x,y \, e^{-x})$ to rewrite the PDE as $\partial u / \partial \xi = 0$ on $\mathbf{R}^2$, which has the general solution $u = f(\eta)$.